# IBM i RPG Program not doing anything

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

The following code compiled under CRTBNDRPG but when running it is stuck on only 1 I/O.

All I hav to do is - all of our tables have order number as 8 but this one file has it as 10. So I am just creating the 2 fields i need one making it 8 and the other is ok as it is. ANy ideas why this little program doesn't take off?

```
FMFHHMH    IF   E             DISK                                    
F* output file                                                        
FMFHHMHPK  O  A E             DISK                                    
D*EXTSHP           S             13  6                                
D                                                                     
C                                                                     
C                   READ      MFHHMH                                  
C                   Dow       NOT %EOF(MFHHMH)                        
C                   iF        %found                                  
c                   MOVE      MHORDR        MHORDp                    
c                   MOVE      MHZONE        MHZONE                    
C                   WRITE     MFHHMHP                                 
C                   READ      mfhhmh                                  
C                   End                                               
C                   END                                               
C                   SETON                                        LR
```

Comment: Never use just `END` to end a command group, instead use the specific end command such as `ENDIF`, `ENDDO`, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have created an infinite loop where `NOT %EOF` is **TRUE** but `%FOUND` is **FALSE**.

Note from the documentation for [%FOUND](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahg%2Frzahgrpglangref.htm) that it does not reflect a status for a `READ` operation.

The `IF` conditional is not needed in your code as the `DOW` loop is sufficient to guarantee you have a record.

Answer (score 3):

It's right what saying James in the first answer .. with op-code READ you can use IF %EOF but you can't use IF %FOUND ....
Use %FOUND with CHAIN

You can also use an sql statement if both tables have a similar structure

INSERT INTO MFHHMHPK
(select * from MFHHMH where whateveryouwant)

Comment: Yes, if possible SQL should be used instead, as something this simple can be **MUCH** faster if in the db-layer only.

Comment: Let's see...  1 SQL statement, or 12 lines of RPG.  SQL is the better choice.